# Is there R function to count the number of matching pairs in 2 vectors

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors A and B. Both are column vectors and both contain 1000 values.
For example:

```
A = c(1,2,5,1,6,2,8,2,9)
B = c(3,4,2,3,7,4,5,4,8)
```

I wish to find out how many times that (A,B) match in a matrix form.
How many times elements of vector A(as rows) is matched with elements vector B(as columns),

eg. [1,3] is `1` from vector `A` is match with `3` from vector `B` two times

```
    A\B   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8

    1     0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0
    2     0     0     0     3     0     0     0     0
    3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    5     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
    6     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
    7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    8     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
    9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

I know that I need to create a for loop and I was hoping the unique command would work but as yet I have been unable to generate a working code.
In MATLAB there is accumarray() function, does R have something similar?

Comment: Could you explain the rules to get the values in the matrix from the vectors A and B?

Comment: Either `xtabs( ~ A + B)` or `lvls <- sort(union(A, B));xtabs( ~ factor(A, levels = lvls) + factor(B, levels = lvls))` will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop if you want, but it is slower than Rui Barradas solution in the comments. Perhaps others have faster loop options.

```
Am = matrix(0, nrow=length(A),ncol=length(A))
for( i in seq_along(A)) {
  Am[A[i],B[i]] <- Am[A[i],B[i]] + 1
}
```

Output:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: i will add that "slower" should be kept in perspective. We are still talking microseconds to complete if A and B are only 1000 values in length